# How to add a report with Crystal Report in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports-2008

I want to add a report with crystal report in MVC 5, but I can not find the action icon! I'm going to add item -> existing item -> and nothing! I have to install it as a tool on its own? How do I do it? any help for me?

I am work in VS 2017

[image: Screenshoot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download Crystal Report templates for Visual Studio. Download from [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/)

and then restart visual studio, you will see Reporting section in add new item screen.